# How can I wrap an Ascii value that exceeds "Z" back to "A" without using If statements?

Tags: java

I can't figure out how to perform this for both lowercase and uppercase. The Ascii value that I'm changing is being shifted by a randomly generated integer between 3 and 7. The purpose of the code is to produce a random credit card number.

```
    char character3 = lastName.charAt(0);
    int ascii3 = (int) character3;

    char character4 = lastName.charAt(firstName.length()-1);
    int ascii4 = (int) character4;

    //testing output
    System.out.println(ascii1 + " " + ascii2 + " " + ascii3 + " " + ascii4 + " ");


    int Ascii1 = ascii1 + finalRandom;
    int Ascii2 = ascii2 + finalRandom;
    int Ascii3 = ascii3 + finalRandom;
    int Ascii4 = ascii4 + finalRandom;

    //Wrapping value back to "a" if it's Ascii value exceeds "z"
    char Wrap1 = (char) Ascii1;
    char translated = (char)('A' + (Wrap1 -'A') % ('Z' - 'A' + 1));

    char Wrap2 = (char) Ascii2;
    char translated2 = (char)('A' + (Wrap2 - 'A') % ('Z' - 'A' + 1));
```

Comment: well you need an if statement to determine if it is passed those points... but when you figure that part out all you would do is either add/subtract the amount of letters in the alphabet

Comment: @3kings The directions for this assignment explicitly say that I cannot use an If statement

Comment: Use a ternary operator?  In any case, it's hard to answer because you haven't defined clearly enough what you're trying to accomplish.  You might try posting some code, and leave a hole for the part you don't know how to do _but spell out clearly what you want it to do_.

Comment: @Jb1128 What have you tried ?

Comment: Please, show your code. You're asking programmer's help, they need to see code.

Comment: Do the directions say you can't use a `while` statement?  `while (ch > 'Z') { ch = 'A'; break; }` would be a way to avoid `if`.  But that could be considered cheating.

Comment: sample of code just submitted

Comment: OK, that gives us more of a hint.  But if you want "an answer that works for both upper and lower case", you will need to tell us what you want the program to do if the value is (1) in the range 0-64, (2) in the range 91-96, (3) in the range 123-65535.  (`'A'`=65, `'Z'`=90, `'a'`=97, `'z'`=122)

Comment: Ummm... where in the world are credit card numbers composed of letters?

Comment: @ajb I planned on converting them back to integer values. The assignment still calls for more operations, I just need to figure this segement out before I can move on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way is to use if statements, but this should also work

```
ch = ( char ) ( ( ch + SHIFT - 'A' ) % 26 + 'A' );
```

The above only works on uppercase characters and fails on lowercase characters. Here is a solution that works on both upper and lowercase characters, completely free of all if/while/for statements.

```
public static char shift( char c, int shift ) {
    int l = c - 'a';
    int u = c - 'A';

    // The '>> 31' operator fills all bits with bit 31 of l
    int mask = l >> 31;

    l = ( l + shift ) % 26;
    u = ( u + shift ) % 26;

    return ( char ) ( ( ( l + 'a' ) & ~mask ) + ( ( u + 'A' ) & mask ) );
}
```

The above solution works by calculating the wrapping shift for both lowercase and uppercase characters and masks out the invalid one. `mask` is `-1` if it is a uppercase character or `0` if it is a lowercase character. This is generated by getting the sign bit after subtracting `'a'` from the desired character which is negative if it is an uppercase character since `'a' > 'Z'`.

Comment: What's `SHIFT` in your answer?

Comment: @ajb from the code he posted it seems like wrapping is what he wants. Doing >'Z' -> 'A' doesn't seem possible without using if statements.

Comment: @Codebender SHIFT is the random integer he wants to shift the character by

Comment: I posted my comment before he posted his code.  Or at least before I saw his edit.

Comment: Also, his question talks about "both uppercase and lowercase"; I don't know for sure what is required, but this simple answer probably won't solve it.

Comment: @Smith_61 *How can I wrap an Ascii value that EXCEEDS "Z" back to "A" without using If statements?*.... your code will produce `B` for `'Z' + 2` with a wrap of 1. Shouldn't ANY value that exceeds `Z` result in an `A` ?

Comment: @ajb Lower case characters would break this

Comment: @MohammadGhazanfar I interpreted it to mean it wraps where 'Z' + 1 = 'A', 'Z' + 2 = 'B', and so on.

Comment: @Smith_61 This works just fine for either uppercase or lowercase but not both. That is my main issue. If you all would like me to post the directions for the assignment, I can certainly do that.

Comment: @Jb1128 to get it to work with both lower case and uppercase without if statements will be interesting. Give me a few more minutes and I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: @Smith_61 Appreciate the assistance. This assignment has had me and the internet stumped all day.

Comment: @Jb1128 Can you clarify if the wrapping is such that 'Z' + 2 = 'B' or if 'Z' + anything = 'A'

Comment: @Smith_61 It is most certainly the 'Z' + 2 = 'B'. Your initial solution was perfect minus the ability to wrap both uppercase and lowerecase.

Comment: @Smith_61 What if I just wrote another ch = ( char ) ( ( ch + SHIFT - 'a' ) % 26 + 'a' );  and changed those capitols to lowercase but pass the same shift value and ch through the operation?

Comment: @Jb1128 You would then have to choose between the two without using an if statement.

Comment: @Smith_61 when I perform what I just proposed, the output is 78 when I input 'z'(122) and the random shift number was 4. It's wrapping but going providing a higher Ascii value than it should.

Comment: @Jb1128 Just added a solution that should work abusing bit manipulations to select between the two different shifts.

Comment: @Smith_61 Wow! Thank you for the help. Where do I learn to do things like that?? Any recommended readings for a new programmer?

Comment: @Jb1128 For general java knowledge the tutorials provided by Oracle are very good. Others might be able to suggest better books, but for the most part lots of practice and reading code written by others is a good way to learn.